# Modify the paper size of generated pdf in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

i use to print pdf a paper smaller than A4 , i need to customize the paper size in my pdf code , how can i do it ?

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', array(210,250), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TCPDF Custom page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948818/tcpdf-custom-page-size)

Comment: No because the printer setting doesn't support my paper size , so if i want to print pdf correctly i need to make pdf size 'a4' and skip 35 mm from left and start put my data , but this is not a good idea i need something else