Generate dynamic table of contents with TCPDF
I am using TCPDF to generate pdf documents.
The source of the file is html with dynamic fields, and this dosnt let me know the right pages to put into my table of contents.
Does somene have any idea ?
Expecting a trick that can help me to find the right solution

what you have tried so far? where is the code you are stacked ?

Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948818/tcpdf-custom-page-size since it contains a similar question. HTML does not contain print formatting or page formatting as a PDF does. It can be difficult to automate pages to PDF from HTML unless the tool you are using contains parsers of special HTML entities that would signify a page break or whatever magic the HTML parser requires.
